# SQL Queries - Creating a Grid from Three Columns

Tags: sql-server

My SQL table has three columns:

```
TaskID   VarID   Hours
001      001     10
001      002     40
001      003     100
002      001     50
002      002     80
002      003     90
```

I want to produce output like the following

```
TaskID     VarID ->   001      002      003
001                   10       40       100
002                   50       80       90
```

I think there is some query or function that can help me do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this fairly easily in SQL Server 2005 and up - the magic word is `PIVOT`.

Here's the query you need:

```
SELECT 
      TaskID,
      [001], [002], [003]
FROM 
    YourTable
PIVOT 
    ( 
        SUM(HOURS)
        FOR VarID IN ([001], [002], [003])
    ) 
    AS YourPivot
ORDER BY 
      YourPivot.TaskID
```

The idea of a PIVOT table is a bit tricky to grok at first - maybe these additional sources of information will help:

- [MSDN: Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)
- [Pivot table for SQL Server](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/pivottableformicrosoftsqlserver/2434/)
- [SQL Server: Pivot table example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/22/sql-server-pivot-table-example/)

The explanation from MSDN might shed some light:

> You can use the PIVOT and UNPIVOT
> relational operators to change a
> table-valued expression into another
> table. PIVOT rotates a table-valued
> expression by turning the unique
> values from one column in the
> expression into multiple columns in
> the output, and performs aggregations
> where they are required on any
> remaining column values that are
> wanted in the final output. UNPIVOT
> performs the opposite operation to
> PIVOT by rotating columns of a
> table-valued expression into column
> values.

So you basically take a variable `VarID` and turn its distinct values (001, 002, 003) and an aggregate over those `(SUM(Hours))` into columns of a new "pivot" table.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

You need a cross-tab query.  Unfortunately, this isn't easy to do in SQL Server.  It's very easy in MS Access (there's a wizard to help.)

You'll need to use the PIVOT function.  I'm using a stored proc like this:

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_pivot_sa_byHomeCare] AS
   DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(1000)

   SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(HomeCareRating as varchar) + ']',
   '[' + cast(HomeCareRating as varchar)+ ']')
   FROM vw_sa_byHomeCare
   GROUP BY HomeCareRating
   --print @columns

   DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)

   SET @query = '
   SELECT *
   FROM vw_sa_byHomeCare
   PIVOT
   (
   sum(count_pmin)
   FOR [HomeCareRating]
   IN (' + @columns + ')
   )
   AS p'

   --print @query

   EXECUTE(@query)
```

where my view (vw_sa_byHomeCare) is the view I want to pivot, HomeCareRating is the column to pivot over, and sum(count_pmin) is my value.